# How to add group_by to fix a postgresql group_by error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am following a railscast episode but I'm using postgresql and am getting a group_by error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "ratings.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT created_at, sum(score) as total_score FROM "ratings" ...
               ^
: SELECT created_at, sum(score) as total_score FROM "ratings"  WHERE ("ratings"."created_at" BETWEEN '2014-01-02 00:00:00.000000' AND '2014-01-23 13:43:06.187741') GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

How should I modify my code below to include group_by created_at

```
def self.chart_data(start = 3.weeks.ago)
 total_votes = votes_by_day(start)
 (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
 {
  created_at: date,
  total_score: total_prices[date] || 0
 }
 end
end

def self.votes_by_day(start)
 ratings = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
 ratings = ratings.group("date(created_at)")
 ratings = ratings.select("created_at, sum(score) as total_score")
 ratings.each_with_object({}) do |rating, scores|
  scores[rating.created_at.to_date] = rating.total_score
 end
end
```

Comment: Any chance you're running an old PostgreSQL version? What does `select version()` output? (Haven't really looked at question to see whether the issue I'm thinking of applies, but you should include your Pg version anyway).

Comment: I'm running (PostgreSQL) 9.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group by clause and your select clause have different attributes. If you're grouping by "date(created_at)" then you can no longer select "created_at."

```
def self.votes_by_day(start)
  ratings = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
  ratings = ratings.group("date(created_at)")
  ratings = ratings.select("date(created_at), sum(score) as total_score")
  ratings.each_with_object({}) do |rating, scores|
  scores[rating.created_at.to_date] = rating.total_score
end
```

Comment: I grouped_by created_at instead of date(created_at) so that I could use created_at in: scores[rating.created_at.to_date]and it worked. Thank you.